# unable to pass variable to other page using ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

I would need some advice/assistance here. I'm trying to pass 2 variable to other page from a link using ajax but when i click the link, there is no response. Seem like my ajax is not working, would appreciate if anyone can assist here. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script  type="text/javascript" src="productshow.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>  
<?php              
$sql = mysql_query ("SELECT  * FROM espaceproduct WHERE email = 'jaychou@hotmail.com' ");    
?>

<?php   
$result1  = array();        
$result2  = array();
$loopCount1 = 0;          
$loopCount2 = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{   
    $result1[] = $row['thumbnail']; 
    $result2[] = $row['id']; 

    $_SESSION['thumbnail'] = $result1;

    //$url = "profileview.php?email=".$result1[$loopCount1].'&'. "id=".$result2[$loopCount2];

    $loopproduct = $result1[$loopCount1];

    $loopid = $result2[$loopCount2];

    echo"<br/>"."<br/>";               

    echo '<a  href="#" onClick="ajax_post($loopproduct,$loopid)" >'. $_SESSION['thumbnail'][$loopCount1] .'</a>'."<br/>" ;
    $loopCount1++;
    $loopCount2++;
}

?>  
    </body>
</html>
```

This my ajax page

```
function list_chats(){
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {          
            document.getElementById("showbox").innerHTML = hr.responseText;         
        }
    }
    hr.open("GET", "productshow.php?t=" + Math.random(),true);
    hr.send();
}

setInterval(list_chats, 500); 

function ajax_post(la,ka){
    // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
    var url = "espaceproductinsert.php";

    var kn = "add="+la+"&csg="+ka;

    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;

            document.getElementById("status1").innerHTML = return_data;         
        }
    }

    // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    hr.send(kn); // Actually execute the request

    document.getElementById("csg").value = "";   
}
```

This is the page where the variables should be insert

```
<?php
$add = $_POST['add'];
$csg = $_POST['csg'];

$sql2 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO espaceproduct ( storename,productname ) VALUES ('$add','$csg') ");

?>
```

Comment: One problem would be this: `ajax_post($loopproduct,$loopid)`. _Hint_: Open your first page in the browser, view source, and see what's there in the `onclick` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In page 1 add this script appropriately

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var httpObject=false;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            httpObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else if(window.ActiveXObject){
            httpObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp");
        }

        function tranferData(){

            var data1= document.getElementById('div1').value;
            var data2= document.getElementById('div2').value;
            var queryString = "?data1=" + data1;
            queryString +=  "&data2=" + data2;

            httpObject.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(httpObject.readyState == 4 && httpObject.status == 200){
                    var error = document.getElementById('error');
                    var response = httpObject.responseText;

                    alert(response);
                }
            }
            httpObject.open("GET", "page2.php"+queryString ,true);
            httpObject.send(null);
        }
    </script>
```

You send the data using above script and recieve from another page

### page 2

```
<?php
echo $_GET['data1'];
echo $_GET['data2'];
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it's work. Now able to pass the value to other page. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Smiply Try this

```
function ajax_post(la,ka){

$.post("espaceproductinsert.php", { add:la, csg:ka},
   function(data) {
           alert(data);
   });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

and on the serverside do this

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($_GET); //for testing replace with array('key'=>$value);
?>
```